# Ez Publish Override Template

Tags: php, ezpublish

Does anyone know how to override this file in EZ PUBLISH..+

> {* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE! Use an override template instead. *}
>   {set-block scope=root variable=subject}{"Collected information from
>   %1"|i18n("design/standard/content/edit",,array($collection.object.name|wash))}{/set-block}
>
> {* Use this line to specify the email of receiver, sender and reply-to
>   in the template,    can read this from the object to make it dynamic
>   pr form {set-block scope=root
>   variable=email_receiver}nospam@ez.no{/set-block} {set-block scope=root
>   variable=email_sender}custom_sender@example.com{/set-block} {set-block
>   scope=root
>   variable=email_reply_to}custom_reply_to@example.com{/set-block}
>   *}
>
> {* Set this to redirect to another node {set-block scope=root
>   variable=redirect_to_node_id}2{/set-block}
>   *}
>
> {"The following information was
>   collected"|i18n("design/standard/content/edit")}:
>
> {section name=Attribute loop=$collection.attributes}
>   {$Attribute:item.contentclass_attribute_name|wash}:
>   {attribute_result_gui view=info attribute=$Attribute:item}
>
> {/section}

it is located in `extension/ezwebin/design/ezwebin/templates/content/collectedinfomail/form.tpl`..

I want to override that file for me to modify the content that I'm going to send in email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you always have two ways to override:

{nice way}
1. you make a file in your template folder under override folder in your own extension and define the new override rule in [override.ini](https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-override-conditions) file of your extension or siteaccess. [read more [here]](https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Templates/The-template-override-system/Template-override-example)

{simpler way}
2. you can create a file with exactly the same path(not under override folder anymore) in your own extension and this file will automatically override the file in ezwebin or any other extension of ezpublish.
Attention: for this method, you should always make sure that your extension is more powerful that the other one. (it should be in upper position in site.ini)